# BackgroundWorker’s sender is wrong

Tags: .net, vb.net

I implemented a progress bar like this:

```
TableCreation.ProgressBar2.Value = 0
TableCreation.ProgressBar2.Maximum = CInt(FieldsNumber)
'==================
For SecondLoopCount = 1 To CInt(FieldsNumber) Step 1
    '----------------------------------------------
    TableCreation.ProgressBar2.Value = SecondLoopCount
    TableCreation.ProgressBar2.Refresh()
    TableCreation.ProgressBar2.Show()
    ' ....... Some Code ......
Next
```

And I handle the `BackgroundWorker`’s `DoWork` event in this sub:

```
Public Shared Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    For i = 1 To 10
        If worker.CancellationPending = True Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        Else
            ' Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            worker.ReportProgress(i * 10)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But when I do this:

```
Dim e1 As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs
TableCreation.ProgressBar2.Value = SecondLoopCount
TableCreation.ProgressBar2.Refresh()
TableCreation.ProgressBar2.Show()
bw_DoWork(sender, e1)
```

Where `sender` is an Object, it throws an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'e_store.TableCreation' to type 'System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker'.

`TableCreation` is just a form in my project.

Comment: what is sender when you call _bw_DoWork(sender, e1)_

Comment: Please never write `= True` or `Step 1`. Also, have you looked at the documentation for `BackgroundWorker` to find out how `BackgroundWorker` is supposed to be used? This is not it.

Comment: @minitech Yes I know that is supposed to be used. And I have search in documentation but unfortunately I can’t understand the use of background worker. It is obvious that I need some help around here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `bw_DoWork()` directly. That's where the error is happening, you're sending the `sender` object in the current context (your form) and then trying to cast it as a `BackgroundWorker`.

You should instead add the handler to your `DoWork` Sub,

```
Public Shared Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
```

And then instead of calling `bw_DoWork()` directly, do `bw.RunWorkerAsync()`. This will then raise the `DoWork` event and call that method. Then, your `sender` will be the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: When I do that to the `bw_DoWork` it thows an error {Handle clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types}

Comment: That's because, in order for this solution to work, you need to drop a `BackgroundWorker` onto your form in the form designer.  You'll find it in the Components section of the tool box.  Make sure you rename it to `bw`, or change the `Handles` clause to whatever actual name you do give it.